# Missing toggle button in settings pane

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

Using the following

```
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
        <gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.15</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

        <java-version>17</java-version>
        <javafx-version>19</javafx-version> (also specifying javafxStaticSdkVersion as 19)
        <charm-version>6.2.0</charm-version>
        <attach-version>4.0.15</attach-version>
```

and graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final, with this simple `View` class as the home view:

```
public class OptionsView extends View {

    public OptionsView() {
        var settingsPane = createSettingsPane();
        setCenter(settingsPane);
    }

    private SettingsPane createSettingsPane() {
        var recording = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        var recordingOption = new DefaultOption<>("Record", "Turn recording on/off", "Connection", recording, true);

        var settingsPane = new SettingsPane();
        settingsPane.getOptions().add(recordingOption);
        settingsPane.setSearchBoxVisible(false);
        return settingsPane;
    }
}
```

The toggle button does not show on Android:

[image]

On desktop it does:

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** I noticed that with `<charm-version>6.1.0</charm-version>` it works fine, so looks like a bug in 6.2.0.

Comment: Can you try 6.2.2?

Comment: @JoséPereda 6.2.2 shows the button. I didn't see an update was released. I see that it doesn't fix some other bug in charm though, so I will post another question shortly.

Comment: 6.2.0 contained a refactor of the skin package (that moved out from `impl`), but there was a small bug in the reflection list from those skin classes which caused exactly your issue, that has been fixed with 6.2.1. And 6.2.2 was just recently released.

Comment: @JoséPereda Understood. I posted this as an answer for now, unless you want to post one yourself.

Comment: That's fine, no problem.

Comment: @JoséPereda Here is the next issue I'm hitting with Charm, if you can have a look at your convenience: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74097583/combobox-in-a-settingspane-makes-selection-with-touch-events-difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment by @José Pereda:

> 6.2.0 contained a refactor of the skin package (that moved out from impl), but there was a small bug in the reflection list from those skin classes which caused exactly your issue, that has been fixed with 6.2.1. And 6.2.2 was just recently released.

Updating to 6.2.2 fixes the issue.