# ComboBox makes selection with touch events difficult

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

This class creates a view with a `ChoiceBox`, `ComboBox` settings pane with a `ComboBox`:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Toast;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;

public class OptionsView extends View {

    public OptionsView() {
        var choicebox = new ChoiceBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("aaav", "bvvv", "cssss"));
        choicebox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        choicebox.showingProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("ChoiceBox On showing: " + nv));
        choicebox.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("ChoiceBox On action: " + e));
        choicebox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("ChoiceBox On selection: " + nv));
        choicebox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> new Toast(nv + " selected").show());

        var combobox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("aaav", "bvvv", "cssss"));
        combobox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        combobox.showingProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("ComboBox On showing: " + nv));
        combobox.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("ComboBox On action: " + e));
        combobox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("ComboBox On selection: " + nv));
        combobox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> new Toast(nv + " selected").show());

        setTop(new HBox(30, combobox, choicebox));

        var bigListView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("AAAAA", "FFFFF", "GGGGG"));
        bigListView.setCellFactory(c -> createListCell(26));
        bigListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> new Toast(nv + " selected").show());

        var smallListView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("aaaaa", "fffff", "ggggg"));
        smallListView.setCellFactory(c -> createListCell(14));
        smallListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> new Toast(nv + " selected").show());

        setCenter(new VBox(bigListView, smallListView));
    }

    private static ListCell<String> createListCell(double fontSize) {
        var cell = new ListCell<String>() {
            {
                textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
                setFont(Font.font(fontSize));
                setOnTouchPressed(e -> new Toast(getText() + " touched").show());
                setOnMouseClicked(e -> new Toast(getText() + " clicked").show());
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setTitleText("Options");
    }
}
```

On Android, when trying to select (with touch events) from the `ChoiceBox`, selection works fine. However, trying to select from the `ComboBox`s does not work properly. The user choice is usually ignored - the dropdown menu closes without a new selection, and only after several attempts it selects another option.

Using

```
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
    <gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.15</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

    <java-version>17</java-version>
    <javafx-version>19</javafx-version>
    <charm-version>6.2.2</charm-version>
    <attach-version>4.0.15</attach-version>
```

with javafxStaticSdkVersion 19 and using graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final.

This occurred with charm 6.1 as well.

When running on desktop, selection with the mouse works fine.

Comment: I've just tested with your exact same versions on my android 10 Pixel XL, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoséPereda I can produce an APK if you think it will help. Could be again an issue with Android 8. I can record a video showing that it happens, but I don't know how much good it will do. I will also look at the unfiltered logcat to see if there's something there.

Comment: I don't mind testing it. I don't see how the Android version could be a problem, it is pretty much in the JavaFX side, but touch events are handled from the Android side. Maybe you can post the full logcat output (just add a link) to compare and see if some events are missing in your case.

Comment: @JoséPereda I modified to code to include both `ComboBox`s and a `ChoiceBox`, The settings pane is not the issue as I have suspected, it's any `ComboBox`. The `ChoiceBox` works fine. I updated the question. Here is the apk for the new code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MqmJX17rYaFyf-ApNcduMJhrBeZBaYBD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Works just fine for me too. We need to compare the logs (as these include all the touch events), can you post a link with your logcat?

Comment: @JoséPereda Here is the log: https://pastebin.com/VZdvmcJE. I added prints for `showingProperty`, `onAction` and `selectedItemProperty` for both the `ChoiceBox` and the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Your logs are pretty much the same as mine, I don't see anything meaningful. If you place the `ComboBox` at the top left coordinates of the view, does it work better? Since the `ComboBox` skin uses a `ListView`, chances are that there could be an issue with the listCell selection. It would be helpful if you could play around with the listCell to add some visual hints that you are touching a cell, or with its selection model, allowing all kind of mouse/touch events, in order to identify is some of them are received or not, if that makes sense.

Comment: @JoséPereda I added 2 `ListView`s with different font sizes and added event listeners as you suggested. I updated the code in the question. The list with the small font is hardly selectable - most touches on its cells produce no events whatsoever, though sometimes "I get lucky" and a cell receives events. The cells in the big list view receive "touched" followed by a "click" event consistently (not even sure why a mouse click event is generated on touch screens...), but not always "selected". New apk: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aDk8oTNwp967bflOsuFmH1qvXHAVpxbW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tested this today on a Galaxy S21 Ultra 5G (Android 12) and it had issues too. The screen us larger and the text is bigger, so it not as difficult as in my Galaxy S7 case, but selection was still not good.

Comment: Hmm, sounds a little bit like you can only select if you hit over "black" pixels with text? In that case, pickOnBounds could help? Have you tried with some background color in the combobox cells?

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried these, no difference. Also, when selection does work, it can happen with touching the extra space in the cell and not the area with the text, so it's not the text pixels. I can record a video to show the problem, but doubt it will help much. As a workaround, I will need to change the visual component in the settings pane from a `ComboBox` to a `ChoiceBox` manually it seems. Do you not have more devices to test on?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you do a "light" touch with the tip of you finger instead of a more long pressed gesture? Also, can you try setting `System.setProperty("monocle.input.touchRadius", "2");` in your main, or even greater? If the touch radius is too small and the device's screen is too sensible, the still gestures can be changed into scroll/other gestures instead of click events...

Comment: @JoséPereda Setting that system property to 2 or 3 works! Click and touch events were generated beforehand too, by the way, just not selection events. So, if the problem is related to the screen of the device, is there a way for me to fix it only on affected devices? Should it be safe to set it to 2 for all devices?

Comment: Great! Based on its [Javadoc](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/monocle/TouchInput.java#L44), a small value on Android allows scrolling after a finger tiny movement, for instance, but if it is too small a single finger tap on a very sensitive device may lead into many touch events on different locations (as these don't get filtered out), which could be interpreted as a scroll event instead of a click event... Probably 2 will be good enough for all kind of devices instead of the current value set for Android (1).

Comment: @JoséPereda Looks like the default there is 20, so why is Android's set to 1?

Comment: 20 is way too big, as it filters out the small movements you make with your finger to start scrolling. Therefore, in order to make scrolling more "organic" on mobile devices, the lower the value the better. However, in your case (which is probably the case of all Galaxy devices), if it is too low, it is like not having a touch input filter at all, leading to selection issues that rely on "still" gestures.

Comment: @JoséPereda Maybe a PR should be submitted to change the default, say to 2 as it's the lowest common denominator we found.

Comment: Feel free to do it? Create an [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues) first and then a [PR](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/pulls) for it? The related code is [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/resources/native/android/c/launcher.c#L69).

Comment: @JoséPereda I was thinking about changing the code in JavaFX from 20 to 2, or is it used in more places and better not be touched?

Comment: Right, that could be an option too. But that affects _all_ monocle devices, not only Android. I'd say that on an embedded device with a low resolution screen you will probably want more 20 than 2. That would be hard to test.

Comment: @JoséPereda Created [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/1183) and [PR](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/pull/1184).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments by @José Pereda, the problem comes from this part of code in JavaFX: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/monocle/TouchInput.java#L44.

This value defines the touch radius for that differentiates touch events from scroll events (hysteresis).

> If the touch radius is too small and the device's screen is too sensible, the still gestures can be changed into scroll/other gestures instead of click events.
> A small value on Android allows scrolling after a finger tiny movement, for instance, but if it is too small a single finger tap on a very sensitive device may lead into many touch events on different locations (as these don't get filtered out), which could be interpreted as a scroll event instead of a click event

Setting `System.setProperty("monocle.input.touchRadius", "2");` in `main` solves the issue.